# Error with Razor.RuntimeCompilation in PublishSingleFile publishing mode

Tags: asp.net

When using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation, using "PublishSingleFile" mode to publish, accessing the page again will result in an error in the program.

The process is as follows:

1.Set the FolderProfile.pubxml config is:
RazorCompileOnBuild:false
RazorCompileOnPublish:false
PublishSingleFile:true
PublishReadyToRun:false
2.Use the RuntimeCompilation:
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

The specific error is as follows:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentException: The value cannot be an empty string. (Parameter 'path')
at System.ArgumentException.ThrowNullOrEmptyException(String argument, String paramName)
at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ValidateArguments(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path).....

My question is, why can't we dynamically compile csHTML files after publishing in single file mode? It seems that the internal program cannot find the corresponding local csHTML file for compilation. How can we solve this problem? Thank you very much!

After using the "PublishSingleFile" publishing mode to publish the asp.net core program, there should have been no access error to asp.net.